# Conditional formatting with drop down menu

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have the following formula to highlight a cell with green:

=AND(A1>=B1,AND(C1<=45000,C1>=4000))

The formula is working fine. Now I am planning to include a drop down list in cell D1 with 3 options (lets say "OPT-1", "OPT-2", "OPT-3"). If I am selecting "OPT-1", it should validate the above formula and if I am selecting "OPT-2", it should validate same formula but the values in the formula will change to 65000 & 10000 instead of 45000 & 4000. Likewise for "OPT-3" also same formula with different value. How can i achieve this with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the [LOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-df82ce98-edf9-46ea-8189-b0470e5e0e93). Note that the values in the *lookup_vector* must be in ascending order.

```
=and($a1>=$b1, $c1<=LOOKUP($D$1, {"OPT-1","OPT-2","OPT-3"}, {45000,65000,100000}), $c1>=LOOKUP($D$1, {"OPT-1","OPT-2","OPT-3"}, {4000,10000,20000}))
```

Note that the nested AND was not necessary. The [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907) might be another choice if you parse off the digit from the righthand side of the options.

Due to your reluctance in providing full details, you will have to edit and provide values for OPT-3.

Answer (score 0):

Add the OPT-n condition to your AND function.
This should work for you:

```
=AND(A1>=B1,OR(AND(D1="OPT-1",C1<=45000,C1>=4000),AND(D1="OPT-2",C1<=65000,C1>=10000),AND(D1="OPT-3",C1<=99999,C1>=88888)))
```